# Algorithm least number of stickers to form target word

Tags: algorithm, hashmap, dynamic-programming

Here's one algorithm problem: We have a target word, (i.e. "history"), we have some "stickers": (i.e "math", "english", "story"). There are infinite number for each sticker. We want to find the minimum number of stickers to form the target word.

A sticker is actually a set of letters. We can split a sticker to use single letters. For target 'history', we can use sticker "story" and "h,i"(2 letters) from sticker "english" to get the "history". So for "history", the minimum number of stickers to use is 2("story"+"english").

I am using Java, so I think a HashMap to represent the target word with occurrence of each letter. Then use backtracking to try each possible combination of stickers. Is there any smarter approach to solve this problem or optimizations can be applied?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the **multiset multicover** problem.

Maybe the dynamic-programming approach of the paper [Exact Algorithms for Set Multicover and
Multiset Multicover Problems](http://i.cs.hku.hk/~fcmlau/papers/isaac09.pdf) is relevant for you.

Apart from Dynamic-programming: the usual suspects in solving this (when an optimal solution is required) are [SAT-solvers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT) and [Constraint-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_programming) with clever formulations. Maybe even [Integer-programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming). I consider SAT as the most promising approach, although not completely trivial (because of multiple equal characters in targets; and because of infinite availability).